# Mixing vectors in R

Tags: r, vector

I was wondering if there were some pre-built function to perform such operation I'm doing by hand right now: creating a new vector from 2 original ones by taking, for example, one data from each iteratively:

```
x = 1:5
y = 10:14
output = c(1,10,2,11,3,12,4,13,5,14)
```

For now I've been using:

```
output = c(rbind(x,y))
```

but it seems a bit dodgy to me and it is case specific to this mixing. I can't do for example:

```
output = c(1,2,10,3,4,11,5,1,12,...
```

thanks

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to do, if you only trying to randomly mix those vectors, just do `sample(c(x, y))`

Comment: What you are doing is _interleaving_ them, and your method is fine. Do you have a need to create a more generalised mixture?

Comment: @DavidArenburg: @martin got me, it is not random mixing, bu with a given pattern, such as 2 from `x` 1 from `y' etc. but keeping the order

Comment: But they are same size. What happens when there are no more observations in `x`?

Comment: I was thinking about recycling, like in the second example `5,1,...`